# Fancybox shifts to the right and down a few pixels after loading

Tags: fancybox

I'm using Fancybox to open an iframe and it works fine in all browsers except for ie.

When ie opens the iframe it seems to stagger for a split second and then it shifts the modal box to the right and down a few pixels.

I came across a few people's posts but their answers didn't help.

I also played around with the CSS with no success.

Anyone came across anything like this before?

Cheers!

Comment: I guess in this case it would be very useful if you show a link

Comment: My bad ( http://www.mytrak.com/homevideos.aspx ), we're working in DNN and when I test locally Fancybox works wonders. I'm guessing it may have to do with the js being called by nivo (used in the above header) but I'm not versed enough to solve that.

Comment: I still think is a DOCTYPE issue, see my update

Answer (score 14):

Hope my solution will help to anyone who still face the same issue... 
I use fancybox 1.x and my DOCTYPE is "html".

I've found that actually the issue was in using `box-sizing: border-box;` in styles reset. So I switched it back to `content-box` for `#fancybox-content` and `#fancybox-wrap` and fancybox started to work properly.

Comment: For those looking for some basic CSS here is what you'd paste into your styles: 

`#fancybox-wrap, #fancybox-content { box-sizing: content-box; }`

Comment: This css fixed it for me beautifully. Thanks!

Comment: Or `#fbplus-wrap { box-sizing: content-box;  } #fbplus-content { box-sizing: content-box; }` if you are using fancybox as [**angular-fancybox-plus**](https://github.com/igorlino/angular-fancybox-plus). Just place this anywhere succeeding the original CSS.

Answer (score 1):

Fancybox needs a proper DOCTYPE to work correctly, specially with IE. Your site is currently running in quirks mode.

You can find a working DOCTYPE reference here.

by this

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
```

In your particular case, you may try changing this

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
```

Answer (score 0):

Fancybox needs a proper `DOCTYPE` to work correctly, specially with IE. Your site is currently running in `quirks mode`.

You can find a working `DOCTYPE` reference [here](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/doctype/).

In your particular case, you may try changing this

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
```

by this

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
```

**UPDATE** : I have created some simple `html` pages to reproduce the issue with IE.

The first one uses the same `DOCTYPE` as in your page as well as the same fancybox code. IE works in quirks mode so fancybox behaves oddly as in your page:
http://picssel.com/playground/jquery/ieWrongDoctype_09feb12.html

The second one uses the proposed `DOCTYPE` as solution. IE works in standards mode and fancybox works properly:
http://picssel.com/playground/jquery/ieGoodDoctype_09feb12.html

My conclusion: use the correct `DOCTYPE`

Comment: Hi JFK, thank your for your response. I tried changing the DOCTYPE to no avail. I tested the code locally and it works on IE perfectly, which leads me to think it's a DNN issue. I'll keep trying other solutions and let everyone know.