# Jquery - Fancybox - Background Page Shift Issue

Tags: jquery, css, fancybox

Fancybox is loading well and everything opens as I want it to, but the issue occurs in the background-- it's visible (and disturbing) that my entire page shifts exactly 8 pixels to the right when the box loads and returns to normal position on box closing.

I can't link to the site as it's on a dev server behind our company firewall.

I'm using the following scripts: Fancybox, Quform, and Jquery Banner Rotator. The fancybox call is occurring inside the rotator.  I haven't modified any widths/heights of the original jquery fancybox CSS.

I have the body width set to 100% and margin set to auto, and internal divs with a min-width of 1138px and margin set to auto.

Does anyone know where I should look to fix the issue?

Comment: most likely because the height of your page it doesn't create vertical scroll bars but fancybox creates them so it shifts the page to make room for them. You may try adding a CSS `overflow-y: scroll;` to the body tag.

Comment: Thanks, I tried that, didn't work. I'll keep plugging away at it. Could be the overlay that Fancybox is trying to create might be the issue, I'm just going to have to narrow it down.

Comment: I could help you better with a link.

Comment: BTW, you never said what version of fancybox and with what browser you have to issue. You can check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/9203557/1055987 if it helps.

Comment: same http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9924495/when-a-fancybox-2-is-activated-a-scrollbar-flashes-on-the-parent-page-causing-t/12798575#12798575

Answer (score 25):

I had a very similar situation recently with Fancybox v2. My initial page had content below the fold and therefore had a scrollbar (perhaps the OP did as well, it's not clear). Firing the Fancybox link caused the same shift in page body and clearing the scrollbar; closing the Fancybox image shifted the body back and re-enabled the scrollbar.

The adjustments to `.fancybox-lock` did not work for me but what did was including the following option when instantiating my Fancybox object:

```
helpers: { 
    overlay: { 
        locked: false 
    } 
}
```

The only caveat is this does not lock your Fancybox to the center of the page if you had scrolling, i.e. the page with Fancybox view is entirely scrollable. For me, it was the lesser of two evils.

Comment: Wow thank you, this saved me from pulling my hair out. Great work.

Comment: Note: this caused other issues for me. The overlay was opening too low, and was disappearing when the browser was sized down. It did fix the shift issue though.

Answer (score 7):

I had the same issue recently. Find `.fancybox-lock` in the fancybox CSS, and change it to:

```
.fancybox-lock {
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0 !important;
    }
```

Voila! :D

Answer (score 4):

You can disable the locking feature:

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
    helpers : {
        overlay : {
            locked : false
        }
    }
});
```

Worked for me.

Comment: This caused other issues for me. The overlay was opening too low, and was disappearing when the browser was sized down. It did fix the shift issue though.

Answer (score 3):

It's a known problem, here you can find out more: [issues, fancyapps @ GitHub](https://github.com/fancyapps/fancyBox/issues/360)

I'm using fancybox2 (version 2.1.5).
I've solved the problem by slightly modifying the 'jquery.fancybox.css'-file:

Find the 'Overlay helper'-section (starts at line 165) and change two rules:

```
.fancybox-lock {
/*  overflow: hidden !important;*/
    overflow-x: hidden !important;
    overflow-y: scroll !important;
    width: auto;
}
```

and the second rule:

```
.fancybox-lock .fancybox-overlay {
/*  overflow: auto;
    overflow-y: scroll;*/
    overflow: hidden !important;
}
```

This works fine enough (imho), although the page is scrollable behind the overlay.

At least the disturbing 'shifting right'-effect is suppressed.

I discovered later that elements which were positioned with "right: 0;" were shifted to the left by the width of the vertical scrollbar.

That is because of a margin-right is set by the fancybox.js-code by appending a style-node inside the head-element.

To fix the problem just modify a single line of code inside the jquery.fancybox.js file or the jquery.fancybox-2.1.5-pack.js file, depending on which one you are using.

in line 2017 of the unpacked version:

```
$("<style type='text/css'>.fancybox-margin{margin-right:" + (w2 - w1) + "px;}</style>").appendTo("head");

// change it to

$("<style type='text/css'>.fancybox-margin{margin-right: 0;}</style>").appendTo("head");

// perhaps comment out the complete line, I haven't testet it though
```

or in the .pack-file (line 46 near EOL):

```
/* [much more code before] */ f("<style type='text/css'>.fancybox-margin{margin-right:"+(d-a)+"px;}</style>").appendTo("head")})})(window,document,jQuery);

// change it to:

/* [much more code before] */ f("<style type='text/css'>.fancybox-margin{margin-right:0;}</style>").appendTo("head")})})(window,document,jQuery);

// or try to remove the "f().appendTo()"-part completely (untested)
```

Answer (score 2):

I just solved it by adding "margin-right: auto !important" to my body element :) This over rules Fancyboxes own margin-right: 0.

Answer (score 0):

In version 2.1.3, comment out lines 1802-1807 (below) in jquery.fancybox.js.

```
if (!this.overlay) {

this.margin = D.height() > W.height() || $('body').css('overflow-y') === 'scroll' ? $('body').css('margin-right') : false;

this.el     = document.all && !document.querySelector ? $('html') : $('body');

this.create(opts);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I used fancybox **v.2.1.4** with a **fixed, centered background** image for the body, and forcing vertical scrollbar to always showing.

```
body{
  background: url('../img/sfondo.jpg') fixed center top;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Despite having forced the display of scrollbar, I had the background-image shift problem with **firefox on mac** (chrome and safari were ok since lion scrollbars don't take space inside the page) and ie,ff,chrome on windows.

So I noticed that if I manually set the **x-offset** instead of the world **center** on the background property **the issue was gone**, so I managed it with a little of jquery in the HEAD of the page:

```
<script>
    function centerTheBackground(){
        var pageWidth = $(window).width();
        var imageWidth = 1920; //set here the width of the background image
        var xOffset = (imageWidth/2) - (pageWidth/2);
        jQuery('body').css('background-position', '-' + xOffset + "px top");
    }


    jQuery(function($){
        centerTheBackground();
    });


    $(window).resize(function() {
        centerTheBackground(); //re-center the background image during window resizing
    });             
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well I just commented the following line in fancybox CSS

```
/*.fancybox-lock {
    overflow: hidden;
}
*/
```

And it started to work fine on:

- fancyBox - jQuery Plugin
- version: 2.1.4 (Thu, 10 Jan 2013)

Answer (score 0):

This did it for me...

```
.fancybox-lock {
        overflow: hidden !important;
        padding-right: 17px;
}

.fancybox-lock body {
    overflow: hidden !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are facing that problem for scrollbar! just trace the scrollbar width and use that width as '*.fancybox-lock*'s '*margin-right*'.
for example,

```
.fancybox-lock{
       margin-right: [your calculated width] !important;
 }
```

This will solve your problem for sure, because i also had that problem once.

Answer (score 0):

If your problem is fixed elements jumping when Fancybox opens, simple add a padding-right: 17px to those elements in your CSS, contained in the .fancybox-lock class.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using fancy box 3 and had the same problem all because my main wrapper was position absolute.

make sure you wrapper is not and it should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

My solution for `"@fancyapps/fancybox": "^3.5.7"`:

```
@import '@fancyapps/fancybox';

.fancybox-active {
  height: 500px; // fix fancybox showing skiplinks
}

.compensate-for-scrollbar {
  margin-right: auto !important; // fix fancybox messing body's margin: 0 auto
}

body.compensate-for-scrollbar {
  overflow: auto; // fix fancybox jerking background because of hiding scrollbar
}
```