# Fancybox bug: html shifts a few pixesl after exit

Tags: jquery, css, fancybox, fancybox-2

The whole body shifts a few pixels left and up after closing fancybox (2.1.5) popup.

Here's what I've tried already:

1. I tried to change    `<!Doctype html>`   to `<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">` and `<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">`
   It didn't work.
2. It didn't help to change fancybox content and wrapper to `box-sizing: content-box.`
3. `body{ margin-right: auto !important;}` also didn't help.
4. I also tried to modify jquery.fancybox.css `.fancybox-lock` and `.fancybox-lock .fancybox-overlay` like here  https://stackoverflow.com/a/24387110/5562716. After this Fancybox started behaving even weirder: after exiting the popup it shifted 50% to the right.
5. If I don't use `body{ overflow-x: hidden; }` it jumps to the very top of the page after user exit popup.

Any ideas what else can I try?

Comment: If it's a bug, have you rised an issue (or checked for existing ones)? https://github.com/fancyapps/fancyBox/issues

Comment: It has been already solved in the latest version of fancybox